# Disable hover in mobile

Tags: css

I have these class, so hen I hover an item it do a transition, the problem is when I´m in mobile view, it exit of browse

```
.ftContainerOut {
  padding-right:10px;
  padding-bottom:20px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  cursor:pointer;
  z-index:1;
}
.ftContainerOut:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  z-index:10;
}
```

I'm trying this to disable it on mobile, but it doesn´t work, only in normal view the transition gets stuck

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px){
  .ftContainerOut:hover  {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Help is very appreciated. Regards

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `display:none` on the `:hover`, as this will make the `div` hide on hover, which wont work. Instead I suggest making it do nothing.

On desktop, you `transform: scale` the item by `1.5`, so on mobile `transform: scale` it by `1`, which as it is already `1`, it will not change.

Same principle for `z-index`, on desktop `:hover` changes it to `10`, so on mobile make it "change" to `1`, but as it is already `1`, again there is no change.

So the `CSS` would be:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .ftContainerOut:hover {
    transform: scale(1);
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

Here's a snippet to try it out.

```css
.ftContainerOut {
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

.ftContainerOut:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  z-index: 10;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .ftContainerOut:hover {
    transform: scale(1);
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ftContainerOut" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: green;"></div>
```

Comment: I'm half asleep but shouldn't that media query be max-width?

Comment: True - I was half asleep then too :/

Answer (score 0):

First change your media query to max-width and then reset the properties that you want to reset for mobile.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
  .ftContainerOut:hover  {
    transform: scale(1);
    z-index:1;
  }
}
```

Also if you want to remove transition in mobile you can also add

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
   .ftContainerOut  {
     transition: none;
   }
}
```